# Why do samba users need to log on to the server first?

Tags: samba

For my students, I am setting up an ubuntu server as an webserver and Samaba file server.
Students are all given a local account. I have added folders to Samba to share with the students. They are accessing the shares from windows machines.

Everything woks fine, but I have one problem I currently cannot tackle.

A student can only get access to the share if they have logged into the server ( not to the share ) at least once, and are then able to read and write as wanted.
In case they did not log on to the server, they cannot couple the share. I get the error:
System error 86.
The specified network password is not correct.

Currently this is my script to add users

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/var/www/html/data/users.txt"
while  IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3
do
    # display fields using f1, f2, f3 from IFS separated file
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $f3)
        useradd -M -N -G $f2 -p $pass $f1
        echo $f3 | tee - |  smbpasswd -s -a $f1
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
        printf 'Username: %s, Groups: %s, Password: %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3" crypt $f3 $pass
done <$file
echo done read $file
```

where f1 is user name f2 are the groups (= users,leerlingen,sambashare ) and f3 is the user password in text format.

The smbpasswd line can actually be omitted while it does not help a bit. Also the group sambashare can be left out.

Since I opt for an automation of enrolling students to the system and Samba, I am not happy to perform a log on for each student individually.

I tried to automate the log on procedure

```
echo passwd | sudo su -c "whoami| more| exit" userX
```

But it did not result in a log on which convinced Samba.
performing

```
sudo su userX
```

and logging in and directly exiting worked fine

So can you help me?

Yours sincerly,
John Val

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Samba4 on Ubuntu and don't require student shell logins to Samba server, most likely you have to look forward to Samba AD.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/#samba4

> #### A note about adding users on Samba version 4.x
>
> Unlike Samba version 3.x and earlier, Samba version 4.x does not
> require a local Unix/Linux user for each Samba user that is created.
> The command is as follows for adding users into Samba Active
> Directory:

```
samba-tool user add USERNAME-HERE
```

> Please see Samba AD DC howto for more info - https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/#samba4